# How can I get the source code for file utility in linux?

Tags: linux, file, timezone

I need do find the timezone data file format. So i need file utility source code to port the executable file to our board.

Comment: https://github.com/file/file

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't. The `file` utility only knows about how to quickly identify a file -- that is, the minimum information needed to determine that this is a image, that is a text file, this is an ODT file etc (the 'magic' as it is called).  It's a mistake to think it knows anything more than that.

Instead, you should look at the 'tzfile' man page, as it is all about the timezone file format. It describes it quite precisely.

Comment: Actually, I am uploading the timezone data file to target board through FTP. The timezone data file name is modified as time_zone_info. So i need to verify the uploaded file is timezone data format or not? FTP will accept any file with name time_zone_info. I need to verify the file format, If it is timezone data format then i need to keep that file in target board otherwise need to throw error to FTP.